# Error when insert in database using php

Tags: php

I building an website and when i insert data in database it works but when i try to insert again,i want to give me error,for example if the data that i inserted before its the same off the data that im inserting now, i want to stay in the same page.And if i never inserted that data i want to insert in databse.

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if($_POST){
$descricao = $_POST['descricao'];
$tipo_divisao = $_POST['tipo_divisao'];


$sql_query = "SELECT descricao FROM divisao WHERE descricao ='$descricao'";
$consulta = mysqli_query($link,$sql_query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($consulta)==1){
 header("Location: Add_Divisao.html");
 exit;
}else{
  $sqlite_query = "INSERT INTO divisao(descricao,Tipo_Divisao,cenario) VALUES ('$descricao','$tipo_divisao',72)";
  mysqli_query($link, $sqlite_query);
  header("Location: Confirm_Divisao_Dispo.html");
  exit;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You are mixing apis `mysqli`/`mysql` -> `mysqli_query` vs `mysql_num_rows`

Comment: also, now is a good time to read up on [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what should i do?

Comment: Your code is wide open to [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/5828/pdo/2685/preventing-sql-injection-with-parameterized-queries). Switch to using [prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/2784/php-mysqli/11958/prepared-statements-in-mysqli) and you should resolve this problem

Comment: change `mysql_num_rows()` to `mysqli_num_rows()`

Comment: Its the same if i put what u suggested

Comment: Change if(mysqli_num_rows($consulta)==1) to if(mysqli_num_rows($consulta) > 0 ) and see if that helps.

Comment: It worked thanks! and how can i do to show an error?